# Applying stack blur in an elliptical area (or: drawing an ellipse top to bottom)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graphics

First: if ordering doesn't matter in [this algorithm](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlur.js), I'd love to know it. Since I don't fully grok the algorithm, though, and I notice that x and y in the loops do seem to affect the output, I am operating on the assumption that executing the algorithm in an arbitrary pixel order will cause it to behave incorrectly. (Putting aside the possibility of not being rectangular causing problems!)

What I'd like to know: how can I produce the set of coordinates contained within an ellipse in left-to-right, top-to-bottom order efficiently? The Bresenham circle/ellipse algorithms are useful, but I am having trouble wrangling them about to execute top-down.

Aside from the Bresenham method, another approach is to follow the edge by incrementing/decrementing one coordinate until it crosses the border, but I'm having difficulty simplifying the relevant equations in order to avoid doing a bunch of trigonometry or square root calculations. This may be premature optimization, but it seemed like the solution was in easy reach...

My ultimate goal: draw an elliptical selection onto a Canvas object based on mouse input and apply a blur to the selected area. If another approach is better suited, please do point me in the right direction!

Bonus: Arbitrary rotations

Edit: seems kind of silly that I can't reply to your answer, but that's a smart approach. I'll see what I can make of it; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you could change the algorithm so it changes the start and end positions of each column and row so it on takes into account the pixels contained in an elliptical selection. The problem with this approach is that it will add quite a few extra conditionals to the inner loop which will degrade performance.

The approach I recommend is to first make a copy of the bitmap you want to blur (to avoid unnecessary calculations, just copy the area under the bounding rectangle of the ellipse). Then you blur that entire bitmap including the areas outside the ellipse. Then you composite the blurred map back into the original one, this time using the ellipse as a mask.

The benefit of this approach is that you can use any shape as a blur mask.

Here is an example that uses EaselJS to achieve a similar effect (The blur used in EaselJS is actually StackBlur): http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/alphamask